# ExcelLibrary - Robot Framework Ride - Import Issue

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, rpa

I had trouble to install `pip install robotframework-excellibrary` on anaconda prompter command, I got the error `Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

[image]

I also have tried to install manually, I got the `zip`file, I extracted the files into `Site-packages` folder, however, when I try to import the `ExcelLibrary`into Ride, it also got an error

[image]

Therefore, I want to know how can I install manually correctly or install via pip without error

I'm using pythn 3.7.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors or code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error directly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read requirements. When I open robotframework-excellibrary pypi page, it says under programming languages:

> Python
>
> Python :: 2.7

so I go and open homepage of the project and see requirements:

> - Python 2.7.4 (Newer versions not tested)
> - Robot Framework 2.8.5 (Newer versions not tested)
> - xlutils 1.7.1 (Newer versions not tested). Access the downloads here, or use pip install xlutils.
> - natsort 3.3.0 (Newer versions not tested). Access the downloads here, or use pip install natsort.

At this point I probably stop trying since I have Python 3.

If I still want to confirm that, I copy & paste the error into Google, and the first link that pops up is someone trying to solve the exact same problem (nevermind it's under a completely different project...): https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-requests/issues/109

So my recommendation is to get compatible versions first.